# Deleting multiple elements from a list until a value is encountered

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list within a list and I want to delete certain elements before i encounter a value in one of the elements. Example given below:

Input:

```
A = [["abc"], ["qwe"], ["zxc"], ["asd"], ["name", "qwe", "qqwe","pos"],["qwerty","lkasd", "banner", "kostop"]] ...
```

Output :

```
Output = [["name", "qwe", "qqwe","pos"], ["qwerty","lkasd", "banner", "kostop"]] …
```

All elements before the element that contains "name" should be deleted.

Comment: @MadPhysicist apologies, i did try some code, couldnt work it out. Was hoping someone could help me out.

Comment: Don't apologize, use the edit button to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), which gives the elements from a sequence after some condition stops being true.

Applying it to your example:

```py
>>> a = [['abc'], ['qwe'], ['zxc'], ['asd'], ['name', 'qwe', 'qqwe', 'pos'], ['qwerty', 'lkasd', 'banner', 'kostop']]
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda x: 'name' not in x, a))
[['name', 'qwe', 'qqwe', 'pos'], ['qwerty', 'lkasd', 'banner', 'kostop']]
```